# You must first run "eb init" when running from script

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wrote a ruby shell script that automates my deployment process.
In the command line when I run `eb deploy` everything works fine. But when I run this from my ruby script I get

`ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".`

Why doesn't this work?

Within my ruby script this is how I tried calling the command

```
`eb deploy`
```

and

```
IO.popen(command) do |io|
  while (line = io.gets) do
    puts line
  end
  io.close
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run `eb init`?

Comment: Nothing, no error, I think because its already initialized. eb deploy works already

Comment: What does `pwd` return inside the ruby script? Is it being run from a different location? You might want to make sure you are in the right directory before running `eb deploy` from the script.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong active directory being used in the ruby script.